# asp.net development server + FF issue. IE OK

Tags: asp.net, iis, firefox

Guys, I've came across this problem I can't resolve myselg, I'm pretty sure I miss something pretty obvious, but that's usually how it is.

I'm developing my asp.net webapp in VS2008, XP SP3. When I want to debug, the asp.net starts the development server and the default browser associated with the vs2008 opens up and loads the page. In IE7 it loads the application, in FF3 I get :

- connection failed (111) connection refused

This problem has just popped out this morning, after the restart of the computer (usually I just put it into a sleep mode) and until now it was working ok for both IE or FF. I can't think of anything that could have had changed since, there were no windows updates, just the antivirus, also I put the solution to SVN (but didn't do update on my end).

Any ideas?

Thanks heaps!

UPDATE:
from FF console:

Request headers
Host: localhost:3691
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,sk;q=0.8,cs;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:3691/CLIENT/Default.aspx
Cookie: tmTOCSaveStateCookie=undefined%2CRESOURCE_1; pmTOCSaveStateCookie=undefined
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Response headers:
Server: squid/2.6.STABLE16
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2009 08:32:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 993
Expires: Thu, 02 Jul 2009 08:32:21 GMT
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 111
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.xyz.xyz
Via: 1.0 proxy.xyz.xyz:8080 (squid/2.6.STABLE16)
Proxy-Connection: close

I've tried to turn off firewall, antivirus but no luck. Has it got something to do with authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do FireFox and Internet Explorer have the same proxy settings ? FireFox doesn't use WinINet which most windows applications use.

I sometimes have the same happen to me when i'm inspecting HTTP traffic with Fiddler and my computer crashes although in that case its the other way around (IE/Chrome etc give me the error message and firefox works splendidly).

Comment: thanks for looking into this Martijn, yes it has the same proxy setting. I seriously have been up n' running without any hassles like this (even after many restarts since) but now I'm just left clueless.

Comment: I had a look at the proxy settings in FF again, and I've noticed that I was missing the 'localhost' in the 'No proxy for:'. I have no idea how could have this changed (!).
thanks again

Comment: AFAIK, Firefox does use Winsock (they didn't reimplement the sockets layer), but not WinINET, which means they have their own proxy settings.

The ASP.NET dev server refuses connections which aren't sent to the loopback adapter and a remote proxy clearly can't proxy to "localhost" if it doesn't know what host was meant.

IE/WinINET cannot be configured to proxy Localhost traffic, which is why you should never have this problem in IE.

Comment: Thanks for clearing WinINet/WinSock up updated post to only mention WinINet